# preventing from animating further on some event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got this code here:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#nav_items > p:first-child").click(function()
    {
        $('html,body').animate(
        {
            scrollTop: $('#main_div').offset().top
        }, 500);
    });
    $("#nav_items > p:last-child").click(function()
    {
        $('html,body').animate(
        {
            scrollTop: $('#about_us').offset().top
        }, 800);
    });
});
```

On element(p) click it scrolls the document to a #main_div or #about_us element. How can I stop it from keep on scrolling if I for example start scrolling with my mouse wheel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen to the `mousewheel` event and use the `stop` method:

```
$(window).on('mousewheel', function() {
   $('body, html').stop();
});
```

Comment: Nice, like to keep it simple, instead of using tons of code like in another answer :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method, combining the use of `$(window).scroll()` and `$('body').on('mousewheel')`, that will demonstrate how to do what you wish:

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/oyn60hor/)</kbd>

```
var scrollPause = 0;

menuItems.click(function(e){
   var href = $(this).attr("href"),
      offsetTop = href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top-topMenuHeight+1;
   scrollPause = 1;
   $('html, body').stop().animate({ 
      scrollTop: offsetTop
   }, 300, function(){
       setTimeout(function(){
           scrollPause = 0;
       },5000);
   });
  e.preventDefault();
});

$('body').on({
    'mousewheel': function(e) {
        if (scrollPause == 0) return;
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
})
```

Notes:

1. In the jsFiddle, the `sp` div is used to visually show status of the scrollPause variable
2. Upon clicking a top menu item, the scrollPause is set to `0` (disallow scroll) and a `setTimeout` is used to re-enable it after an 8-second pause. Therefore, immediately after the scroll-to-element, mouse wheel scroll will be disabled for 8 seconds.